# PostgreSQL INSERT - auto-commit mode vs non auto-commit mode

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and still learning a lot as I go.  My company is using PostgreSQL and we are populating the database with tons of data. The data we collect is quite bulky in nature and is derived from certain types of video footage. For example, data related to about 15 minutes worth of video took me about 2 days to ingest into the database.

My problem is that I have data sets which relate to hours worth of video which would take weeks to ingest into the database. I was informed part of the reason this is taking so long to ingest was because PostgeSQK has auto commit set to true by default and committing transactions takes a lot of time/resources. I was informed that I could turn auto commit off, due to which the process would speed up tremendously. However, my concern is that multiple users are going to be populating this database. If i change the program to commit after say every 10 secords and two people are attempting to populate the same table. The first person gets an `id` and when he's on say record 7 then the second person attempts to insert into the same table they are given the same `id` key and once the first person decides to commit his changes, the second persons `id` key will already be used, thus throwing an error.

So what is the best way to insert data into a PostgreSQL database when multiple people are ingesting data at the same time? Is there a way to work around issuing out the same `id` key to multiple people when inserting data in auto-commit mode?

Comment: Can you describe your process of importing information to postgres DB? It looks like you are doing something wrong. Postgres can process gigabytes of data per minute on good hardware.

Comment: I'm working with datasets that contain over 200k entries at one of the top most levels of the database. My sub tables are over 500k entries. It doesnt help that I have to verify that the data doesn't already exist in the tables before i attempt to enter the data. At first it inserts data relativaly fast but as the table entries continue to grow it slows down considerably.

Comment: Few milions of entries isnt something special. I bet, the whole data processing can be done in hew hours. If you can describe the process in details (in separate questions) - I bet there will be an answer that will speed it up drasticly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the IDs are coming from the `serial` type or a PostgreSQL sequence (which is used by the `serial` type), then you never have to worry about two users getting the same ID from the sequence. It simply isn't possible. The `nextval()` function only ever hands out a given ID a single time.